# Store Values generated in a while loop on a list in python

Tags: python

Just a simple example of what i want to do:

```
numberOfcalculations = 3
count = 1
while contador <= numberOfcalculations:
    num = int(input(' number:'))
    num2 = int(input(' other number:'))
    
    calculate = num * num2
    print(calculate)
    count = count + 1
```

How do i store the 3 different values that "calculate" will be worth in a list []?

Comment: `lst.append(calculate)`  create the list outside of the while loop first.  `lst = []`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : Adding data to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029227/python-adding-data-to-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize `calculate` as list type you can append values with `+` operator:

```
numberOfcalculations = 3
count = 1
calculate = []
while count <= numberOfcalculations:
    num = int(input(' number:'))
    num2 = int(input(' other number:'))
    
    calculate += [ num * num2 ]
    print(calculate)
    count = count + 1
```

Also you have to change contador somehow or you will end up in an infinite loop maybe. I used count here instead to give the user the ability to input 3 different calculations.